What is the difference between a 3c-4e bond vs 2 covalent bonds?
A 3c-4e bond is a bond in which 4 electrons are shared between 3 centers, but 2 covalent bonds between 3 atoms is also the sharing of 4 electrons between 3 centers (according to MOT)? Where is the distinction between the two bonds made? After doing some research I discovered one possible distinction:
Between each pair of centers in a 3c-4e bond there is a bond of bond order 0.5, whereas in a normal covalent bond there is a bond order of 1.

The difference is very simple. In a 3c bond, you construct the molecular orbital as a combination of atomic orbitals of 3 different atoms. The electrons in those molecular orbitals are shared amongst the three atoms.

Be aware of using bond order lightly it is helpful to describe bond properties but it is not always a well define property
